# TCL/Expect:: How to automate the router booting scnerio?

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to automate the following scenario:

1. Login into a router
2. Give reload
3. When router is rebooting, press ESP key continuously.
4. When pressing a ESP key , boot> prompt will come. execute some commands in this.

I can do the above things manually, using "Teraterm" and console. But how to do this inside a TCL\Expect script.

Please help me to do this.

Thanks, Balu P.